# Upgrade Apache 2.4.6 to 2.4.27 without losing config

Tags: apache, centos, apache2, upgrade

I wan to updage my currently active apache v2.4.6 to latest ver 2.4.27. (CentOS 7)

I know how to install from stracth but I just want to upgrade the version with my configurations remain stil.

Would it be okay to remove whole httpd content with `/etc/httpd, /run/httpd, and /usr/lib64/httpd`with takin configuration backup, then install 2.4.27 from scratch and paste the old config files?

Thank you in advance for any guidance

Comment: Did you ever solve this problem?

Comment: @Vadim Unfortunately, no

Answer (score 6):

You can backup everything and add [CodeIT rpm repo](https://codeit.guru/):

```
cd /etc/yum.repos.d && wget https://repo.codeit.guru/codeit.el7.repo
yum install -y epel-release
yum upgrade httpd
```

Please also be sure to merge your SSL configuration and mpm defaults to have new features like HTTP/2 protocol support enabled.

Comment: Thank you Alexander, I will try this as soon I as backup everything completely. I was afraid of upgrading this since the active system has 600+ concurrent online user

Comment: You are completely right, Lunatic, as usually it won't start first time after upgrade. Problems are usually minor (default ciphers configuration, mpm selection), but you should be able to rollback in seconds.

Comment: You can also check for problems other users experienced in comments: https://codeit.guru/en_US/2017/08/apache-httpd-2-4-27-built-against-openssl-1-0-2l-with-http2-for-red-hat-enterprise-linux-and-centos

Comment: this was helped me to enable HTTP/2 protocol

Comment: @ShankarSBavan How did you enable HTTP/2 protocol ? I have tried a lot but not getting success to enable HTTP/2.

Comment: you got any error? I just followed those commands.

Comment: @RamRam Please compare your config with our ssl.conf bundled (or check with bundled one).
Main things are: 
Protocols h2 http/1.1
SSLCipherSuite "EECDH+AES128:EECDH+AES256:+SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:RSA+3DES:!DSS"
SSLProxyCipherSuite "EECDH+AES128:EECDH+AES256:+SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:RSA+3DES:!DSS"
SSLProtocol +TLSv1.2 +TLSv1.3
SSLProxyProtocol +TLSv1.2 +TLSv1.3